# How to calculate active and inactive statistics without loading all data of table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to calculate this 2 Statistics:

1) Active Categories

2) Inactive Categories

```
var query = context.Category.ToList();
var categoriesStats = (new
{
    active = query.Where(t => t.IsActive).Count(),
    inactive = query.Where(t => !t.IsActive).Count(),
});
```

Is it possible to do this without loading all categories data and then counting active and inactive statistics??

Comment: do it in the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual with multiple aggregates, you can use `group by` **constant** technique to get the result with a single database query.

Also you'll get better SQL translation if you use `Sum(condition ? 1 : 0)` rather than `Count(condition)` (or `Where(condition).Count()`).

```
var categoriesStats = (
    from c in context.Category
    group c by 1 into g
    select new
    {
        active = g.Sum(e => e.IsActive == true ? 1 : 0),
        inactive = g.Sum(e => e.IsActive != true ? 1 : 0),
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I like this one, it is a smarter sql

Comment: @GiladGreen This guy is an expert in writing linq queries and i guess this query would have been a piece of cake for him :)

Comment: @Learning - This is what I love about SO - you always get reminders of stuff you knew and you always learn new things

Answer (score 3):

```
var query = context.Category;
var categoriesStats = new
{
    active = query.Count(t => t.IsActive),
    inactive = query.Count(t => !t.IsActive)
};
```

1. Do not use ToList, this materializes the entire DbSet from the database.
2. Use Count directly, there is no need for where.

Comment: In case of mine query there will be a single round trip to database and in case of your query there will be multiple 2 round trip to the database.please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Learning - you are correct. However returning all records is much more expensive than just returning the count (a single record). So if you have 1000 records your query would return all 1000 records once while the modified (above) query would do 2 trips to the db to get one record each. The former version (1000 records) would be much more expensive to execute as number of results matters.

Comment: @Learning - trying to get it down to one trip could be considered a micro-optimization, it depends on how expensive each DB hit is. In this case it seems fairly cheap but I/we have no other context on what else might be going on at the same time.

Comment: +1 for your explaination.whenever i ask question on SO i get lots of knowledge from you guys.Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single query, like this:

```
var counts = context
    .Category
    .GroupBy(t => t.IsActive ?? false).ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key
    ,   g => g.Count()
    );
var res = new {
    Active = counts.ContainsKey(true) ? counts[true] : 0
,   Inactive = counts.ContainsKey(false) ? counts[false] : 0
};
```

Unlike approaches that use `context.Category` twice, the approach with `GroupBy` makes a single roundtrip to the database to fetch both counts at once. The counting would be done on the RDBMS side, so you wouldn't need to load all categories into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ToList`:

```
var query = context.Category;
var categoriesStats = new
{
    active = query.Count(t => t.IsActive),
    inactive = query.Count(t => !t.IsActive),
};
```

Having the `ToList()` at the beginning executes the query which will be `select * from category`. Without it you will get now 2 queries of: `select count(*) from category where isActive = 1` and one for the other.
Though this results in 2 rounds to the database the amount of data returned is just the `int` of the counting and not all the records of the objects.

Another option, and in this way to go **only once** to the base, is to use `GroupBy`:

```
from c in context.Category
group c by ((c.IsActive ?? false) ? "Active" : "Inactive") into g
select new { State = g.Key, Amount = g.Count() }
```

Comment: So here I will have 2 round trip to the database and in case of mine i would have single round trip??

Comment: @Learning - even though it will go twice to the database the amount of data that is transferred is a fraction of the amount of passing all the objects and then counting in memory

Comment: Thank you so much for giving the answer and most importantly writing explaination which gives lots of knowledge and better understanding to me.Thanks alot

Comment: You guys are responsible for making SO beautifull.